# How to add my custom WPF control to the ToolBox by using the WPF ToolBox Control template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, toolbox

I have a custom control packed as myControl.dll. How to install it in VS2010 by using the WPF ToolBox Control template? I do not want to use the "Choose Toolbox..." or "Drag and Drop" techniques.

Comment: Did you ever check this link? http://blogs.msdn.com/quanto/archive/2009/06/12/how-do-i-deploy-a-toolbox-control-as-a-vsix.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a thorough tutorial article on the topic:

[Visual Studio Toolbox Control Integration](http://www.componentowl.com/articles/visual-studio-toolbox-control-integration)

The "Choose Items..." is easiest choice for manual installation and is discussed in the article as well.

You can also bundle the control in VSI, VSIX or VSPackage, use VS Automation Object Model (DTE) or existing package pre-installed with VS2010 and newer called Toolbox Controls Installer (TCI).

Drag and drop does not work for VS Toolbox as far as I know.